# How to add dependency in Gluon Project

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-8, javafxports

I have my custom jar file suppose to be added in the classpath of my Gluon project, but I couldn't find any facility in Netbeans that allows you to add your custom jars. Can someone guide me on how to do it?

[image]

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b9'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.rameses.Main'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}
```

Comment: @Joeri Sykora, Sir, do you have any idea about this one?

Answer (score 3):

Though I do not use Netbeans or the plugin you have mentioned, but since it is a gradle project, you can add the custom jars to your classpath by adding the following code in your `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/custom.jar')
}
```

where,

`libs/custom.jar` is the relative path of the jar w.r.t to the gradle file.

Comment: Sir, please see the update question, where should I put the code you suggested in my build.gradle.

Comment: You can try adding it inside the `dependencies {...}`

Comment: How do I merge two dependencies, what will be the separator? I tried comma but it didn't worked.

Comment: A gluon project is a regular gradle project with the jfxmobile plugin applied.  As @ItachiUchiha mentioned, in gradle you define your dependencies in the `build.gradle` file. Write each dependency on a new line. Look at the gradle documentation on [dependency management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) for more information.

Comment: It worked for me when adding paranthesis. I assume that it is required when you do more than 1 compile.That means I also had to put paranthesis around my original `compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.7` - line. Notice that that line only says `compile`, and not `compile files`. What is the difference between those?

Comment: @Joeri Sykora .However the `android.jar` is linked to via the android sdk path. Gradle checks inside `gradle.properties` file and find the path there. Assumingly you should not add dependencies inside the `build.gradle` like that when it comes **Android dependencies**, but use Android Studio ---> Android SDK Manager to download them instead?

Comment: @Lealo I would recommend to add android sdk to your system's path. This way you do not have to add anything to `gradle.properties`. Moreover, you should also switch from Android Studio to IntelliJ IDEA as AS is not the preferred IDE for developing Gluon apps. Gluon also provides a [plugin](http://gluonhq.com/get-started/ide-plugins/) for IJ, Eclipse and NB for easier integration of Gluon apps with these IDEs.